# Нужно ли обособлять устойчивое выражение?

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология, деепричастный-оборот

Является ли "не зная куда" устойчивым выражением и не требует обособления ?
Или это деепричастный оборот и запятая нужна?

— Ты уверен? Ты не можешь вот так все бросить и улететь, не зная куда!

Answer (score 1):

*— Ты уверен? Ты не можешь вот так все бросить и улетЕть, **не зная кудА**!*

Устойчивый оборот может обособляться или не обособляться в зависимости от структуры предложения и расстановки логических ударений. Но всё-таки чаще оборот обособляется.

Для сравнения: *Ты не можешь вот так все бросить и улететь **неизвестно кудА**.*

Примеры:

...и эти люди вмиг стали мне чужими, как и все люди на земле. *Я стал пустой и шЁл, **не зная кудА**.* [Александр Григоренко. Ильгет. Три имени судьбы // Урал, 2013]

Я иду за Раисой, иду без ее, так сказать, ведома, и у меня почему-то подламываются ноги. *Поэтому я иду **не зная кудА**, мЕдленно.*  [Галина Щербакова. Моление о Еве (2000)]